# Android Spinner : Show toast if the user select previous hour or minutes based on CURRENT time

Tags: android, datetime, datepicker, android-spinner

I have two spinners with id's `hh` and `mm` and with global array list

```
String[] pickup_hour = { "HH", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06",
        "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
        "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23" };

String[] pickup_min = { "MM", "00", "05", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30",
        "35", "40", "45", "50", "55" };
```

`Spinner` pickup_hour :

```
sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hh);

    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 


        int hour = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            edsp3.setText(pickup_hour[position]);


                         if(position<hour)
                         {
                             Toast.makeText(OnlineBooking.this, "Choose greater hour",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }}
@Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter b3 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pickup_hour);

    b3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp3.setAdapter(b3);
```

`Spinner` pickup_min:

```
sp4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mm);
    sp4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        int minutes = c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position1, long id) {
            Log.d("bbb", ""+minutes);
            edsp4.setText(pickup_min[position1]);

             if (position1<minutes){
                 Toast.makeText(OnlineBooking.this, "Choose greater minutes",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter b4 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pickup_min);

    b4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp4.setAdapter(b4);
```

QUESTION : I'm trying show a `Toast` if the user selects any previous hour and any previous minute based on the CURRENT time. My code isn't working out.

How can i fix this and achieve what's desired?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in your condition:

```
 if(position<hour)
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(OnlineBooking.this, "Choose greater hour",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

change it to:

```
 String hourSelected = pickup_hour[position];
 if(Integer.parseInt(hourSelected)<hour)
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(OnlineBooking.this, "Choose greater hour",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

And when using Integer.parseInt ensure that the position is not == 0, since if HH is selected, it will throw UnSupportedNumberFormat exception.